# "18 часов" или "18 часов вечера"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как грамотно сказать: "18 часов" или "18 часов вечера"

Answer (score 10):

Если о времени суток, то 18 часов ( 18 часов утра не бывает, слово вечером лишнее). А вот если 6 часов, то утра или вечера, чтобы было ясно.

Comment: Спасибо! 
Ребенок (3 класс) участвовал в конкурсе. а там было такое задание
В Древней Греции и Риме на цветниках высаживали растения, цветки которых открывали и закрывали свои венчики в разное время суток. 
Из перечисленного списка цветов выбери те, которые закрываются и показывают:
1. 11 часов утра.   
2. 17 часов вечера.
3. 20 часов вечера.

Поэтому-то я и засомневалась!